# Downloading and Moving OneDrive files from shared link directory

Tags: rest, onedrive

I am looking for assistance to find out how I can download and move a OneDrive file that is accessed through a shared directory, via the shared link method of sharing.

I have two users:

- user 'A' who is a Microsoft Consumer and has a regular OneDrive account and will host a csv file 'test.csv' in a folder 'toshare'
- and user 'B' who is also a regular Microsoft Consumer who should use the graph API to download test.csv and then move the file to a subdirectory /toshare/archive

*Aside: I am currently using the chrome app "advanced REST client" to manually make the REST calls, and am getting Authenticated OAuth BEARER tokens by inspecting network traffic from Microsoft's online "Graph Explorer" tool. After we understand the calls, we'll integrate it into our Java app.*

I have succesfully followed the instructions here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/shares_get 
to view the folder contents.

To be more explicit, user 'A' has went into OneDrive and has right clicked the folder 'toshare' and selected shareLink. I have converted the shareLink to a share token and then used the following API call with the Graph API as user 'B':

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<share-token>/root?$expand=children
```

this shows me all the files in the directory, which includes 'test.csv'

**Now, using this information, how can I download test.csv?** Assuming user 'B' doesn't know the name of the file, but can identify it by being a .csv file (we can do this in code). There does not appear to be much documentation on how to download the files through a share.

The closest I've gotten was to take the "webUrl" attribute of the children object for my file, and then turn that into a share token and call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<child-share-token>/root
```

This will show me the file meta-data. and then I try to download it by roughly following the api documentation to download https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<child-share-token>/root/content
```

This is interesting because this works if I make the call with user 'A' but does not work for user 'B' who instead gets a 403 in advanced REST client. (If I run it in Graph Explorer, I get "The site in the encoded share URI is invalid." instead, which I've discovered with other experimentation, really means there's an authorization issue.)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<share-token>/root:/test.csv:/content
```

Also does not work, it returns: "400 Bad Request" with message: "Resource not found for the segment 'root:'."  It seems like the path style file navigation does not work for shared directories?

At this point I'm rather stuck. After downloading the file, I also would like to move it into a subdirectory, denoting that it has already been read in. I'd also like to get this working for OneDrive for Business, but that seems to be another set of challenges that I'll leave for another day.

Any insight would be great thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Since, then I've given up with trying to programatically deal with the shares approach. We are now using delegated permissions, to access user directories explicitly. The documentation for that is very clear and works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to consider the `shares/{id}` segments to be similar to `drives/{id}`, at which point all of the previous documentation around children access is applicable. Given your scenario I'd use the path syntax:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<share-token>/root/children/test.csv
```

This obviously necessitates knowing the file name, but it sounds like you already have an algorithm to do that.

Theoretically your approach for creating a `child-share-token` would work, but it would now require that User B both provide authentication as well as to have explicit permissions. Since your `share-token` was a sharing link User B is most likely getting permission by virtue of the fact that they have the URL, in which case generating a new one is probably removing the special token that allows this to work. That's why it's best to always use the original `share-token` where possible.

Similar rules will apply to move the file. First off, we'll assume that the sharing link provides the ability to "Edit" otherwise none of this will work :). Second, we'll assume that the `archive` folder already exists (if it doesn't you'd need to create it using a POST to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<share-token>/root/children` that looks like what we've documented [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm)).

To move the file you'd want to PATCH to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<share-token>/root/children/test.csv` and provide a new `parentReference` as documented [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/move.htm). It's always best to use `id` values if you have them, but you should also be able to provide the `path` to the parent in the form of `/shares/<share-token>/root/children/archive`.

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<share-token>/root/children works fine and shows me the meta-data of the test.csv:  "name": "test.csv". your example gives me a "400 Bad Request": "Resource not found for the segment 'root:'."

Comment: could we use the @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl link? I can see that in the /root/children results. The documentation made it sound like it's a pre-authenticated link to the source data file. But I'm not quite sure how to use it.  https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm
Thanks for your help by the way. =D

Comment: Hi @fei0x, I've updated the answer to remove references to the colon syntax as apparently it's not yet working for shares. Thankfully you should be able to reference the children via the `children` collection. re: the downloadUrl - you can just make a web request against it (without an `Authorization` header) and it'll return you the content of the file.

Comment: Thanks Brad; so that seems to be the correct way to format the path. However, now I appear to be running into an authorization problem. Your solution seems to work when I use the auth token for the user who created the share (user 'A') but not for other users (they get 403 Forbidden with no response), I've noticed that the redirect location header for those to scenarios differ and for user A i can link there directly and download the file, but not for user B. The downloadUrl links appear to also have the same issue, the link from the source user works, other users get a 403.

Comment: Also starting to wonder if I should instead be taking the /approot approach instead. Was thinking that a little more complex, but maybe easier to get working and more correct? Although having some issues with the tokens I generate following: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm to work. I'm getting: 401 Unauthorized with message: "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184118".  I am using the 'access_token' from the results of the call to https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf as my Bearer token as described in the documentation.